# UTF8 mysql data appearing incorrectly in a single MySQL field

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

My data in one of my Database columns is not displaying correctly from UTF8.

I recently converted the MySQL database to UTF8 using:

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

When displaying data using my **PHP** script one field appears to not display correctly:

**Â£25**

When Im expecting:

**£25**

Other fields on the same page correctly display £25. The only difference I see is that they are VARCHARs and the problem field is MEDIUMTEXT.

Why does this one field not display correctly (it isn't treated any differently by my script).

Any help ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just convert the collation like that and not expect issues. There are many problematic characters that are not converted automatically.

What's happened is you likely had a non-UTF8 friendly character (like those MS Office produces) and when you converted it got mangled. If it's just a few fields, I would open them in an editor and remove the offending data. Otherwise you may have to "scrub" your database of these strange characters using a loop and something like [utf8_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

Answer (score 0):

What was the CHARACTER SET of the column before converting?

A3 is the hex for latin1 £.

C2A3 is the hex for utf8 £, but it displays as Â£ if treated as latin1.

Possibly you only need to declare that your php program is using utf8:

```
⚈  (deprecated) mysql interface: mysql_set_charset('utf8'); (assuming PHP 5.2.3 & MySQL 5.0.7) Note: "mysql_" interface is deprecated.
⚈  mysqli interface: mysqli_set_charset('utf8') function. See mysqli_set_charset
⚈  PDO interface: set the charset attribute of the PDO dsn.
```

Please do `SELECT HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...`.  If you get `C2A3...`, then you have correctly converted the table to utf8.  If you get `C382C2A3...`, you have the dreaded "double encoding".  I discuss that further in [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll).

Since you seem to have different fields showing different things, you are likely to have different encodings.  Beware, things are getting harder and harder to untangle.

Comment: Before Character set was "latin1;"

Now it is: "DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;" 

I ran the HEX on the column I get for "£25"= C382C2A33235

So its some kind of double encoding then ? How do I fix it... shall revert my databse back again to Latin 1 ?

Comment: Well, that probably means that the data in the table (when it was latin1) was wrong!  Can you start over -- that is, load the data fresh?  If so, let's first talk about establishing "utf8" end-to-end.  If not, we'll need to dig deeper into the various clients, tables, etc.

Comment: I solved the problem Im in UTF8 now. There was two problems one was double encoded field and second was the field was being changed with the PHP dom call $html->saveHTML().